# Creating shortest route using line segment layer as network locations?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, routing, linear-referencing, network-dataset

Using ArcGIS Desktop 10.2.1, I am trying to create a truck route that begins at one location on a county street grid and ends up in the same place, obeying a feature class of guard rail line segments throughout an entire county - we need the shortest possible.

I need to use these line segments as network locations. However, the only line-based NA objects that can be defined as network locations are line and polygon barriers. But I'm not trying to avoid each guardrail, just follow it.

I tried creating centroids and vertices from each segment to use as stops (on a single road as a test), but found out it sends me on this 1000 mile rat race to connect 3 points in a neighborhood road.

Is there a problem with how the tool is interacting with the LRS itself?

This seems like it would be a common problem, yet I haven't been able to find anything on it.

Comment: You are using a Vehicle Routing solver and not just a Route solver, correct? Converting your lines to either centroids (may need to create a point constrained to the shape rather than a centroid depending on the lines) or start/end points is a good approach. Are you allowing it to re-order stops? Are you using distance as your impedence? Are there turn or one-way restrictions? Some screenshots of your settings and results would be helpful here.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use lines as stop inputs for a network analysis. The only way you could possibly use the lines is to set them as barriers but give them a negative value (ie, rather than adding time, they take time away) such that they attract the route rather than avoid it. You still have to set stops though.

If centroids are not sufficient, it would be suggested to create points out of the start and ends of the guardrail sections. Unless the analysis is set using a curb approach restriction, you won't be able to define which point is the start vs end. If you *do* use a curb approach restriction, then you know based on direction of travel which will be the start and which the end. U-turn restrictions, etc, will also play a role. Your vehicle routing problem will need to allow reordering of stops for greatest efficiency.