# Using line feature as stops input in network analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, network-analyst

I'm trying to build a certain route with network analyst on a Network Dataset. As an input to create the route I want to use line features. I am trying to do this with network analyst in ArcGIS 10.0 to connect these lines into the shortest route. But this seems to give me only the opportunity to insert stops as the network analysis objects.

I tried to use points for the stops, by making a point on both ends of those separate line features and add them as the input locations. But then I get in some cases an insufficient output because one of the lines which I want in my route is not included. This is for example because the points are in a square and the longest line is not included in the route then because I search for the shortest route, but actually I want that line in. I also tried to find a tool to make instead of points on both ends of the lines a lot of points on the line with a very small interval to be shore the lines that I want to be in the route will be included in the route by the network analyst tool. But I cannot find such a tool for ArcGIS 10.0.

Can anybody give me some solutions for this problem?

Regarding the last comment of Chris W, I made a new question: [Is it possible to make stops not in a certain sequence in order to find the shortest route with the network analyst?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122989/is-it-possible-to-make-stops-not-in-a-certain-sequence-in-order-to-find-the-shor)

Comment: The Densify (Editing) tool will add vertices to your lines at a specified distance.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/100102/ but it won't let me flag it as such because the answer there isn't upvoted. The short answer is you can't use lines for stops, as a stop is a *point* on the network. To solve your desired edge not being included problem, you could add an additional stop at the midpoint of each line to help coax the route along that segment. If it's a long edge though, you may still end up with an 'out to the middle and back' route depending on the next stop. The problem is you want it to reorder *pairs* of stops instead of individual stops.

Comment: Densify requires Standard or Advanced and will add vertices to your edges as @Maksim suggests. You may or may not need more vertices though, as what you need are points for stops. To get points out of those vertices automatically, the easiest way is [Feature Vertices To Points](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Feature_Vertices_To_Points/00170000003p000000/), which requires Advanced. The number of stops on an edge to make sure it takes the edge will vary, but I wouldn't go too overboard or your analysis will really slow down.

Comment: It would be better to edit this question to remove your new question and picture and post that as a separate, new question. The general SE policy is 'one question per question' to keep things simple and easy to answer or get clarification on. I'm not sure what you mean by 'equal points'. When you allow a route to reorder stops, the numerical sequence of the points as stops doesn't matter because it will automatically reorder them to create the shortest route. Showing the actual stop points in your graphic would be helpful, as well as highlighting the start and end points.